# django eliminate users out of queryset if they appear more than once

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a recordset that captured a load of data, ie how many times someone has bought something.

I am working on a small notification system based on their previous purchases that sends them an email if they have have bought something in a specific category.

it could be that this user appears more than once in that recordset and last thing I want to do is annoy someone by sending them 50 or 60 emails on one day.

Is there a way that I can cycle through the data and only get one user per Category?

Here is what I have

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_backed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paypal_transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

**Here is what I am running at the moment**

```
customers = Customer.objects.annotate(Count('user__id')).order_by()
```

**result:**

```
[<Customer: user1>, <Customer: user2>, <Customer: user1>, <Customer: user1>, <Customer: user1>, <Customer: john>, <Customer: user1>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .distinct() method. It will prevent data duplication, so all users will appear only once in queryset.

```
customers = Customer.objects.annotate(Count('user__id')).order_by().distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using distinct:

```
customers = Customer.objects.annotate(Count('user__id')).distinct()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'quite'?